# Range can't iterate over true when it displays everything correctly?

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm having a weird issue with Go templates. For some reason when I use double `range` it stops rendering everything below it in the code.

```
// Index.html
{{define "index"}}
    {{range $k, $element := .Items}}
        {{range $element}}
            {{.Title}}
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

This is my Go code:

```
data := IndexData{
    Items: items,
}

IndexTemplate := template.Must(template.New("skeleton.html").Funcs(FuncTemplate).ParseFiles("skeleton.html", "index.html"))
IndexTemplate.ExecuteTemplate(w, "skeleton", data)
```

It does show the data correctly on my page and there are no errors. The only problem here is that it stops the rendering of the page after the last item is displayed.

In my skeleton I display my templates like this, depending on what page they're visiting:

```
// Skeleton.html
{{define "skeleton"}}
    {{block "index".}}{{end}}
    {{block "account.register".}}{{end}}
    {{block "account.login".}}{{end}}
    {{block "account.profile".}}{{end}}
{{end}}
```

Why does it stop rendering after the last item is displayed from the range?

**EDIT:**

Only error displayed is `executing "index" at <$element>: range can't iterate over true`

**EDIT 2:**

`.Item` is a `map[string]interface{}` that contains the following:

```
map[result:[map[Title:Hello World2 Content:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet2...] map[Title:Hello World Content:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...]] success:true]
```

**Solution**

I managed to solve this by properly returning the data I need to use without the `success:true` part as well as using it as `interface{}` so I don't have to use 2 range loops.

Comment: @ThunderCat `executing "index" at <$element>: range can't iterate over true` although it displays all data from the map correctly. I don't understand this error.

Comment: @ThunderCat I see. Question edited.

Comment: @ThunderCat I discovered that and managed to fix the issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer range iterates over a map with the keys `result` and `success`. The inner range attempts to iterate over the values for these keys. The value for `success` is `true`.  It's not possible to range on a bool.

Change the template range over `result` only:

```
{{define "index"}}
        {{range .Items.result}}
            {{.Title}}
        {{end}}
{{end}}
```

Also, modify the code to check and handle the error returned from `ExecuteTemplate`.

Comment: This is more efficient than me having to simply return just `result`. Cheers for that!